# My form does not send data to the db django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-templates, django-views

My form does not send data to the database.
I have a form that after entering data and clicking 'Order' should send information to the database. However, this does not happen.

It is a 'cart' which, after sending the data, should save in the Order table information provided by the user as well as data on ordered products.

**cart/views.py**

```
def cart_detail(request, total=0, counter=0, cart_items = None):
  try:
      cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
      cart_items = CartItem.objects.filter(cart=cart, active=True)
      for cart_item in cart_items:
          total += (cart_item.product.price * cart_item.quantity)
          counter += cart_item.quantity
  except ObjectDoesNotExist:
      pass
  if request.method == 'POST':
    total = request.POST['total']
    billingName = request.POST['billingName']
    billingAddress1 = request.POST['billingAddress1']
    billingCity = request.POST['billingCity']
    billingPostcode = request.POST['billingPostcode']
    billingCountry = request.POST['billingCountry']
    shippingName = request.POST['shippingName']
    shippingAddress1 = request.POST['shippingAddress1']
    shippingCity = request.POST['shippingCity']
    shippingPostcode = request.POST['shippingPostcode']
    shippingCountry = request.POST['shippingCountry']

    order_details = Order.objects.create(total=total, billingName=billingName, billingAddress1=billingAddress1, billingCity=billingCity, billingPostcode=billingPostcode,billingCountry=billingCountry, shippingName=shippingName, shippingAddress1=shippingAddress1, shippingCity=shippingCity, shippingPostcode=shippingPostcode, shippingCountry=shippingCountry)
    order_details.save()
    for order_item in cart_items:
                    oi = OrderItem.objects.create(
                            product = order_item.product.name,
                            quantity = order_item.quantity,
                            price = order_item.product.price,
                            order = order_details
                        )
                    oi.save()
                    '''Reduce stock when order is placed or saved'''
                    products = Product.objects.get(id=order_item.product.id)
                    products.stock = int(order_item.product.stock - order_item.quantity)
                    products.save()
                    order_item.delete()
                    '''The terminal will print this message when the order is saved'''
                    print('The order has been created')
    return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
  return render(request, 'cart/cart.html', dict(cart_items = cart_items, total = total, counter = counter))
```

**orders/models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Order(models.Model):
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='GBP Order Total')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    billingName = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    billingAddress1 = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    billingCity = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    billingPostcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    billingCountry = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    shippingName = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    shippingAddress1 = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    shippingCity = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=True)
    shippingPostcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    shippingCountry = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Order'
        ordering = ['-created']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name='GBP Price')
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'OrderItem'

    def sub_total(self):
        return self.quantity * self.price

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product
```

**templates/cart/cart.html**

```
<button class="btn send-click btn-md my-1 btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#inquiryModal">Complete Order</button>

                                <!-- Inquiry Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="inquiryModal" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="inquiryModalLabel">Complete Order</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
            <span>&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
            <form action="{% url 'cart:cart_detail' %}" method="POST">
          {% csrf_token %}

            <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="billingName" class="col-form-label">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="billingName" class="form-control" 
                    value="" required>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="billingAddress1" class="col-form-label">Adress:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="billingAddress1" class="form-control" 
                        value="" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="billingCity" class="col-form-label">City:</label>
                            <input type="text" name="billingCity" class="form-control" 
                            value="" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="billingPostcode" class="col-form-label">Post code:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="billingPostcode" class="form-control" 
                                value="" required>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                                <label for="billingCountry" class="col-form-label">Country:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="billingCountry" class="form-control" 
                                value="" required>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="shippingName" class="col-form-label">Shop name:</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="shippingName" class="form-control" 
                                    value="" required>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="shippingAddress1" class="col-form-label">Shop adress:</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="shippingAddress1" class="form-control" 
                                        value="" required>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                            <label for="shippingCity" class="col-form-label">Shop City:</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="shippingCity" class="form-control" 
                                            value="" required>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="shippingPostcode" class="col-form-label">Shop Post code:</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="shippingPostcode" class="form-control" 
                                                value="" required>
                                            </div>

                                            <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="shippingCountry" class="col-form-label">Shop Country:</label>
                                                    <input type="text" name="shippingCountry" class="form-control" 
                                                    value="" required>
                                                </div>
                                            <hr>
                                <input type="submit" value="Order" class="btn send-click btn-md my-0 btn-block">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**cart/urls.py**

```
app_name='cart'

urlpatterns = [
    path('add/<int:product_id>/', views.add_cart, name='add_cart'),
    path('', views.cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('remove/<int:product_id>/', views.cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
    path('full_remove/<int:product_id>/', views.full_remove, name='full_remove'),
]
```

Comment: What does happen?

Comment: the 'if' probably condition does not work. I have no error information. I'm already sitting on it a lot and nothing comes to my mind. My form does not save data to db.
I need a fresh look.

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST':` does not work?

Comment: Probably yes. Because the data is not saved.
In fact, I don't know where the error is anymore, but certainly in those elements which I have inserted.

Comment: Probably? You've not done any debugging at all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203938/discussion-between-yellowhand-and-iain-shelvington).